# Environment variables in cygwin ssh session

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I installed cygwin and sshd on a winXP Box. sshd runs as service.
(I used 'ssh-host-config' to configure and 'cygrunsrv -S sshd' to start it)

Now I login and execute a command from a linux box using the usual ssh client in 2 different ways:

1. using users password authentication:

   `ssh jenkins@192.168.xxx.xxx "cmd /c echo %userdomain%, %username%"`
2. using public key authentication:

   `ssh -i /path/to/private_key/id_rsa jenkins@192.168.xxx.xxx "cmd /c echo %userdomain%, %username%"`

The output is:

1.) winxp_hostname, jenkins

2.) NT AUTHORITY, SYSTEM

Could somebody explain how this happens: Why the user belongs to different domains. ... and where I can tune/influence this ?

Comment: Try using `/usr/bin/bash.exe -cl 'cmd ...'` instead. Look as though one of above is missing environment variables.